# How to apply withCredentials inside factory ngResource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found that I could withCredentails: true to enable sending cookies with client requests.
My question is how do I do the same, but for resources from factory?
I have code looking like this:

```
angular.module('myappServices', ['ngResource']).
  factory('User',function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://' + host + '/api/user', {}, {
      query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false},
      save: {method: 'POST',
        isArray: false
      }
    });
  })
```

Comment: Hope you have checked this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1095

Comment: Yes, I have checked it and set that option to true by default. Thanks!